# MKAnnotationView images are not changing

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

[image]

I am trying to show images in MKAnnotationView. The images are loading initially but when I am trying to change the images for a few on a button click the images are not changing rather they are overlapping. Below is the code I have used.

**MapView Delegate**

```
extension MapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "MapAnnotation") as? MapAnnotationView

    if annotationView != nil {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }
    else {

        annotationView = MapAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "MapAnnotation")
    }

    annotationView?.canShowCallout = true

    return annotationView
}
```

**MKAnnotationView**

```
class MapAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {

// Required for MKAnnotationView
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

    super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    //super.prepareForReuse()
  guard let attractionAnnotation = self.annotation as? MapAnnotation else { return }
    if attractionAnnotation.type == PinType.hospital {
    image = UIImage.init(named: "hospital_green")

}
}
```

**Button Action**

```
@IBAction func btnGreen_Click(_ sender: Any) {
    for annotation in (policyMapView?.annotations)! {
        let mapAnnotationView = policyMapView?.view(for: annotation) as? AssistMapAnnotationView

        //if !(mapAnnotationView?.annotation is MKUserLocation) {
        if !(mapAnnotationView?.annotation is MKUserLocation) {

            let mapAnnotation = annotation as? AssistMapAnnotation

            if mapAnnotation?.type == PinType.hospital {
                if (mapAnnotation?.insurer_id == selectedInsurer1) {
                    mapAnnotationView?.image = UIImage.init(named: "hospital_purple")
                }else{
                    mapAnnotationView?.image = UIImage.init(named: "hospital_green")
                }
            } 

        } else {

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Create a new annotation with the updated images, and set the new annotation, while removing the old ones.
Annotations are immutable once added to the mapkit

Comment: What is `AssistMapAnnotationView ` ? Maybe you have to use `MapAnnotationView ` instead of `AssistMapAnnotationView `

Comment: It is just the class name of type MapAnnotationView.